# How to avoid repetitive call of method in java?

Tags: java, performance

I have written a method which returns a Hash Map.  I am calling this method from many places at different methods every time  the function will return the hash map with the same value. Is it possible to use the value returned from first call of the function instead of calling them every time.

Comment: I guess you can make it static or create a singleton if you are sure the value will always be the same. Can you give us this function ?

Comment: You can use Singleton pattern to ensure all caller same object.

Answer (score 4):

If the method that returns the `HashMap` creates a new `HashMap` instance in each call, you can improve performance by caching the `HashMap` this method returns in an instance or static variable (depending if this is an instance method or static method) and returning that variable if it's not null.

```
private HashMap map; // I used a raw HashMap since I don't know what key and value your
                     // actual HashMap requires
public HashMap getMap () // you should consider returning a Map instead of a HashMap
{
    if (map == null) {
        map = new HashMap ();
        ... init the map ...
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Agree with @Eran. You can look info about singleton pattern, and how to implement it, but it is quite similar to what eran has answered.  Agree with Tim too... :)